# How to change the state value using a click button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I write a JSX code in order to create a reset button in which i can made a reset to the timer value using "state".The problem is when i click to the button nothing happends instead of getting the value changed.(Even when i want to display a console msg through the reset function nothing happends)

A created a "state.timer" variable in order to add the value of to display.
A function to made the reset to the "timer" value and change it to 0.
A button which call the reset function in order to made the reset.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timer: 90
    };

    function resetTime() {
      this.setState({ timer: 0 });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>{this.state.timer}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.resetTime}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Expected to display 0 when i click to the reset button instead the value still display 90.

Comment: You are accessing the method setState statically.. it should be `this.setState({timer:0})`...

Comment: nothing change, i think that the onClick button doesn't work.

Comment: I changed the code of the reset function by testing it through msg display console.log but also nothing happends.I think that the click button doesn't work.Here my code:  https://codesandbox.io/s/033xl8kjmn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

You had a few things wrong.

1. You need to use `this` instead of `Timer` when accessing `setState` (ex: `this.setState()`)
2. You need to wrap the onPress callback in an anonymous function so the `context` isn't lost (ex: `onPress={()=>this.resetTime()}` )

#### [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

Writing `const {timer} = this.state;` is exactly the same as `const timer = this.state.timer;`

Think of it as a simpler and more elegant way of accessing properties.

Why seperate it ? Well image if you had multiple properties in state (not just timer). That would mean you would have to write `this.state.timer`, `this.state.someOtherProperty`, `this.state.somethingElse`. Why do that and make it harder to read, when you could just do this.

```
const {timer, someOtherProperty, somethingElse} = this.state;
```

#### Code updated:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timer: 90
    };
  }

  resetTime() {
    this.setState({ timer: 0 });
  }
  render() {
    const { timer } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>{timer}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.resetTime()}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2vm5lnxj4n).

Comment: const { timer } = this.state . Please as beginner programmer can you explain me this code. You are calling this.state.timer through this code ? because i didn't understand { timer } i know only the this.state.variableName in order to call a state value.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. You will need to bind the function to the constructor.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timer: 90
    };
    this.resetTime = this.resetTime.bind(this);
  }

  resetTime() {
    this.setState({ timer: 0 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2>{this.state.timer}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.resetTime}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can also you an arrow functions but this technique relies upon the proposed class property feature. To use this approach, you must enable [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) or enable [stage-2 in Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2/). If you are using Create-React-App it will be already configured.

```
 resetTime =()=> {
      this.setState({ timer: 0 });
 }
```

Comment: Or you can use arrow functions ```resetTime = () => { ... }``` instead of bind in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The state corresponds to the component instance, is not a static variable of your class. Instead of accessing via `Timer.setState` call it from the instance with `this.setState`.